# Java project 3D points to 2D screen

Tags: java, swing, 3d, 2d

```
package Behr;

public class Cam {

    private Point3D point;
    private Degree angleZ; //vertical
    private Degree angleY; //horizontal

    int width, height;

    private double FOV = 90;

    private static Cam INSTANCE;

    private double sensibility = 0.001;

    private int renderdistance = 2;


    private Cam(Point3D point, Degree angleZ, Degree angleY) {
        this.point = point;
        this.angleZ = angleZ;
        this.angleY = angleY;
    }

    public static Cam getInstance(Point3D point, Degree angleZ, Degree angleY) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Cam(point, angleZ, angleY);
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public int getRenderdistance() {
        return renderdistance;
    }

    public void setRenderdistance(int renderdistance) {
        this.renderdistance = renderdistance;
    }

    public double getSensibility() {
        return sensibility;
    }

    public void setSensibility(double sensibility) {
        this.sensibility = sensibility;
    }

    public double getFOV() {
        return FOV * (180 / Math.PI);
    }

    public void setFOV(double FOV) {
        this.FOV = FOV;
    }

    public void setWidthHeight(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }


    public static Cam getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Point3D getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public Degree getAngleZ() {
        return angleZ;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point3D point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public void setAngleZ(Degree angle) {
        this.angleZ = angle;
    }

    public void setAngleY(Degree angle) {
        this.angleY = angle;
    }

    public void setAngles(Degree angleY, Degree angleZ) {
        setAngleZ(angleZ);
        setAngleY(angleY);
    }

    public Degree getAngleY() {
        return angleY;
    }


//    public Point2D projectPoint(final Point3D point) {
//        double mul = 1 / Math.sin(getFOV());
//
//        Point2D out = new Point2D(0, 0);
//        double deltaX = point.getX() - getPoint().getX();
//        double deltaY = point.getY() - getPoint().getY();
//        double deltaZ = point.getZ() - getPoint().getZ();
//
//        // x
//        double delta_z_angle = getAngleZ().get() -
//                Math.atan2( // beta
//                        deltaY,
//                        deltaX
//                );
//
//        out.x = Math.tan(delta_z_angle * mul + 0.5) * (double) getWidth();
//
//        // y
//        double delta_y_angle = getAngleY().get() - Math.atan2(
//                deltaZ,
//                Math.sqrt(
//                        Math.pow(deltaX, 2)
//                        +
//                        Math.pow(deltaY, 2)
//                )
//        );
//        out.y = Math.tan(delta_y_angle * mul + 0.5) * (double) getWidth();
//
//        out.isFrontOfCamera = Math.cos(delta_z_angle) > 0;
//
//        System.out.println(out.getX() + " " + out.getY());
//
//        return out;
//    }


    public Point2D projectPoint(Point3D point) {
        double mul = 1 / Math.sin(getFOV());

        Point2D out = new Point2D(0,0);

        // x
        double delta_z_angle = getAngleZ().get() -
                Math.atan2( // beta
                        point.getY() - getPoint().getY(),
                        point.getX() - getPoint().getX()
                );

        out.x = (
                Math.sin(delta_z_angle) /*Math.sin(Math.PI - delta_z_angle)*/ * mul + 0.5

        ) * (double) getWidth();

        // y
        double delta_y_angle = getAngleY().get() - Math.atan2(
                point.getZ() - getPoint().getZ(),
                point.getX() - getPoint().getX()
        );
        out.y = (
                Math.sin(delta_y_angle) /*Math.sin(Math.PI - delta_y_angle)*/ * mul + 0.5
        ) * (double) getWidth();

        out.isFrontOfCamera = Math.cos(delta_z_angle) > 0;

        System.out.println(out.getX() + " " + out.getY());

        return out;
    }
    public int[] getChunkCoordinates() {
        return new int[]{point.getX() % 16, point.getY() % 16};
    }


}
```

Basically what this should do: it should generate a 3D world in which i can walk (swing gui, ik its not the best but its a fun project)
Now it is only project the positive x points, if i am not mistaken correctly
the commented out code is another way we tried but didnt succeed

Its just like everything else is working fine and this isnt

Heres a picture of how it looks like:

[working side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IA2x.png)
[corrupted side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9HMe.png)]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, how do I fix this so it displays it on the one side like on the other I tried quite a lot but it still doesn't work, it should be an error in the calculations